# "Method name expected" error when trying add a handler method to a delegate - C#

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, handler

I keep getting the error "Method name expected" when trying add the a method to a delegate. I have a delegate which is invoked when ever my game ends. The function I'm trying to add to the delegate stops a countdown from flashing (the method is in a static class). I've searched about and I'm still unsure why its not working. Here is the line causing the error:

`LivesManager.gameEnded += new LivesManager.EndGame(CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this));`

The `this` passes the current form to the method so it can disable the timer flash on the form.

I have added methods from static classes to the same delegate before and it works fine, the only difference is that I'm passing the form as a paramater and then it doesn't like it.

Is there any way to pass the form to the method without the error?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming a little bit since you haven't included the definition of `gameEnded` or `EndGame`. I believe the problem is `CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this)` is not a method name, but actually a method *call*. The compiler is trying to pass the eventual return value of this method call to a `LivesManager.EndGame` constructor, whereas `LivesManager.EndGame` is most likely a (void parameterless?) Delegate.

Perhaps you intended:

```
LivesManager.gameEnded += 
    new LivesManager.EndGame(() => CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this));
```

Or simply:

```
LivesManager.gameEnded += () => CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this);
```

Comment: This works thank you :) But I'm a little confused about the lambda expression: From my knowledge of lambdas the parameters of the method would be in the `()`, like `new LivesManager.EndGame((this) => CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer);` could you explain this please?

Comment: The parameter names of the anonymous function created by the lambda go inside the parentheses. So `(this) => ...` would try to make a function with one parameter named "this", similar to a method with `ReturnType MyFunc1(int this)` (which would barf because it's a reserved word). A lambda expression of `() => ...` is similar to a method `ReturnType MyFunc()`, where `ReturnType` in this case is `void` since nothing is being returned. So `() => CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this)` is similar to `void MyFunc() { CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this); }`

Comment: Ok I think I get it :) Just one more question: how come new `LivesManager.EndGame(() => CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this));` works the same as `() => CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this);`? I've been learning about delegates recently referring to [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13607/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-Delegates). In that tutorial, a delegate is given a handler method like `LivesManager.gameEnded += 
    new LivesManager.EndGame(() => CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this));`. Is there anything lost by using the simpler version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda expression:

```
LivesManager.gameEnded += () => CountdownManager.DisableFlashTimer(this);
```